# Free space in /

Tags: linux, rhel

I need to free space in '/dev/sda5' which is mounted in '/'. I have also some other devices that ar mounted (eg '/dev/sdb1' on '/home' , '/dev/sdc1' on 'var/log' ... ).
I have tried `du -sh *` but it takes too much time to check each directory. This is a production machine running RHEL.

How can i get a list of the folders that belong to '/' (/dev/sda5) and not to other mounted devices to find where i can free space?

```
[root@myservername ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5              27G   24G  2.4G  92% /
/dev/mapper/vg--log-root00
                       25G  3.4G   21G  14% /var/log
/dev/sda2              25G   11G   13G  45% /home
/dev/sda1              99M   12M   82M  13% /boot
tmpfs                  47G     0   47G   0% /dev/shm
```

Any other tip to free space will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to count space on one file system only, the `-x` flag to `du` prevents `du` traversing between file systems.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is exactly what i needed to get the listing of folders in '/dev/sda5' along with disk usage. Now i need to see what can be deleted in order to free space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
find / -type d -xdev
```

From `man find`:

> **-xdev**
>
> Don't descend directories on other filesystems.

Comment: It did not solve my problem but, it is a really good tip. Thanks again.